# How to use my pc as a physical mouse or keyboard for android?

Tags: android, mouse

I want to use my laptop's touchpad as a standard physical mouse or less preferably a keyboard for my android phone (whose touchscreen is screwed). Is there any way I can write a C/C++(other languages) software to make my pc act as a physical mouse/keyboard for the android or any other way you consider worth trying.

You see I cannot enable developer mode or install an app (as touch is not working). Also I don't have an OTG cable (that seems to be the easiest way out, but I want to do it the hard way).

In short, I want to fool android to see my laptop's usb connection as a physical mouse or keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same Scenario and here is the guideline to solve it.

---

**The main barriers are:**

1. You cannot Use the touchscreen
2. You don't have USB debugging enabled
3. Your phone is Locked with a pattern

**What You will need**

1. The Android SDK
2. [Nexus ToolKit](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1995688)
3. [Vysor](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vysor/gidgenkbbabolejbgbpnhbimgjbffefm) for Chrome

**The Process**

1. Boot your phone to recovery and select fastboot
2. Run the Nexus Toolkit and unlock the bootloader
3. Once in CWM you can start to use ADB
4. Open up the command prompt, go to your SDK/platform tools folder/ to access ADB.exe
5. Run `adb devices` command
6. start Vysor and select the phone on the list

---

That's All. You can even cast the screen on your PC